# expected declaration or statement at end of output in a function

Tags: c, input, declaration

I have a function named character_game that is supposed to be called in main() with two parameters, the correct character answer and number of tries. When I try to compile it, it says: utilities.c:133:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input, which 133:1 is the very end of the code that contains the closing bracket for the function.

Here is the code, I could not figure out what was wrong with it, and my Teacher Assistant was not able to figure out also.

Here is the entire utilities.c code, that contains other functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "utilities.h"


int random_value(int lower_limit, int upper_limit);


void draw_square(int size, char ch){

   int row, col = 0;
   for(row = 0; row < size; row++){
      for(col = 0; col < size; col++){
           printf("%c",ch);
      }
      printf("\n");

   }


}


void draw_triangle(int size, char ch){

   int row;
   int spaces_to_print;
   int stars_to_print=1;
   int previous_stars;

   for (row == 1; row < size; row++){

      previous_stars = stars_to_print;
      spaces_to_print = size-row;

      while (spaces_to_print > 0){
         printf(" ");
         spaces_to_print--;
      }

      while (stars_to_print > 0){
         printf("%c", ch);
         stars_to_print--;
      }

      if (stars_to_print == 0){
         printf("\n");
         stars_to_print = previous_stars+2;
      }
   }


}

int number_game(int correct_answer, int max_guesses){

   int guessed_num;

   do{
      printf("num?");
      scanf("%d", &guessed_num);

      if (guessed_num > correct_answer){
         printf("too high\n");
      }

      if (guessed_num < correct_answer){
         printf("too low\n");

      }

      if (guessed_num == correct_answer){
         return 1;
      }


      max_guesses--;
      printf("max guesses now: %d\n", max_guesses);
   }while (max_guesses > 0);

   return 0;


int character_game(char correct_answer, int max_guesses){

   char guessed_char;
   int correct_case = 0;
   int guessed_case = 0;
   int guessed_char_interval1, guessed_char_interval2;

   do {
      printf("letter?\n");
      scanf(" %c", &guessed_char);

                                            printf("guessed_char is: %d\n", guessed_char);
                                            printf("correct_answer is: %d\n", correct_answer);
                                            printf("guessed character is lower character? 0:no. Else:Yes. (%d)\n", islower(guessed_char));

                                            printf("guessed letter is %c\n", guessed_char);
      if (guessed_char < correct_answer){
         printf("too low\n");
      }

      else if (guessed_char > correct_answer){
         printf("too high\n");
      }
      else if (guessed_char == correct_answer){
         if (islower(guessed_char)){
            guessed_case = 1;
         }
         if ( islower(correct_answer)){
            correct_case = 1;
         }
         if (guessed_case == correct_case){
            return 1;
         }
         else{
            printf("wrong case\n");
         }

      }

      max_guesses--;
      printf("max_guesses now: %d\n", max_guesses);

   } while (max_guesses > 0);



}
```

I know that the code is not yet complete, and I have yet to fix it. But I cannot compile it to test it any further. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: So what else is in utilities.c?  Anything that would #define something out, earlier compiler errors?  As is, this compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not put the closing bracket in your function.

```
int character_game(char correct_answer, int max_guesses){

  char guessed_char;
  int correct_case = 0;
  int guessed_case = 0;
  int guessed_char_interval1, guessed_char_interval2;

  do {
     printf("letter?\n");
     scanf(" %c", &guessed_char);

                                            printf("guessed_char is: %d\n", guessed_char);
                                            printf("correct_answer is: %d\n", correct_answer);
                                            printf("guessed character is lower character? 0:no. Else:Yes. (%d)\n", islower(guessed_char));

                                            printf("guessed letter is %c\n", guessed_char);
     if (guessed_char < correct_answer){
        printf("too low\n");
     }

     else if (guessed_char > correct_answer){
        printf("too high\n");
     }
     else if (guessed_char == correct_answer){
        if (islower(guessed_char)){
           guessed_case = 1;
        }
        if ( islower(correct_answer)){
           correct_case = 1;
        }
        if (guessed_case == correct_case){
           return 1;
        }
        else{
           printf("wrong case\n");
        }

     }

     max_guesses--;
     printf("max_guesses now: %d\n", max_guesses);
  }while (max_guesses > 0);
} // ----> Missing
```

Comment: the closing bracket is right under the while(max_guesses >0);.

Comment: In your original question it was not there, it was added later. Kindly post full code (with main etc). For me it compiles fine unless you are using some stone age compiler.

Comment: @Euuug,it wasn't obvious at first because it was formatted incorrectly but the Question has been subsequently edited.

Comment: That is the Exact error anyone will get with the original code. http://ideone.com/Sat5dO -`prog.c:48:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input`

Comment: Here is what i mean - http://ideone.com/KnL33D - chances are maybe the person who edited the original question edited and added the `}` or it was added later by OP. If that is not the problem @Euuug please post full code - this is not the part of the problem.

Comment: The entire utilities.c is now added.

Comment: oh wow, I am dumb. I found out the problem. I realized that I was missing a closing bracket in the previous function... Thank you for your help!!